# PostProcessing in XNA 4

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, post-processing

I am trying to implement a PostProcessing manager in my 3D engine, but I'm failing.  I keep getting the first texture just slapped over the top of everything else.  I'm just creating a new `RenderTarget2D` using the `GraphicsDevice`'s `Viewport` in order to set the Width, Height etc. but it just overwrites everything.

Does anyone have any ideas?  My understanding of the `RenderTarget2D` was that it took a "snapshot" of the screen and then I can redraw that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you aren't setting your `RenderTarget2D` more than once, also use the GraphicsDevice's viewport to create your `RenderTarget2D`

Comment: I never thought that overwriting the RenderTarget2D twice would cause a problem, but I removed one of them and now it's working.  Thanks